# Can side effects on test drug be not fully disclosed and still ethical?

Tags: scientific-method, medical-ethics, experiment

Say a doctor invites a patient to test a new drug, because there is currently no effective drug to cure the illness. The patient says "I trust that what you are doing is best for my benefit. I'll take it."

But to avoid placebo/psychological effect, are they allowed to not fully disclose all side effects that the drug has, even when they know it? For example, they know ahead that the drug will make the patient nausea and body burning, but they just say that it will make them mildly dizzy. Is that ethical? The patient should have been informed all these effects before accepting the experiment – failing to do that breaks the trust they put on the doctor. But if telling their expectations to the side effects can distort the actual results.

I'm interested in the case of no treatment is available, but without a treatment the patients only continue to suffer the illness, not die.

<sup>Related: [Is it ethical to deliberately provide incorrect information to participants in a psychological study?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21303/12937)</sup>

Comment: While an interesting topic, I think the question if open for a broad spectrum of answers and even opinions.

Comment: [..and their ethical principles concerning placebo, is still missing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18154590), other sources unfortunately in german [Placebo in der Medizin](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/77606/Stellungnahme-des-Wissenschaftlichen-Beirats-der-Bundesaerztekammer-Placebo-in-der-Medizin) [Therapie zum Schein - ist es ethisch vertretbar, Placebos zu verschreiben?](https://www.thieme.de/de/presse/placebos-32873.htm)

Comment: @bummi I think Ooker is heading in a different direction, which is also interesting. In a clinical trial, side effects of a drug are tested. With approved drugs, one needs to disclose all side effects to the patient, but what during trial? Obviously, for the first few, one had no clue. But then - Do you say „50% of our test subjects experienced headaches“. This might indeed trigger a certain expectancy within the patient so that those patients, who know the side effects have more side effects. (Which I can guarantee at least on a study with n=1, myself.) This would totally ruin the trial.

Comment: @Narusan maybe that's why we have double blind study? So that the researchers who give drugs to the patients don't really know the side effects? So that not only reduces expectancy in the patients, but also the expectancy in the researchers, which the patients may read out? Only the researchers who collect data can know the results, but they don't tell this to the ones who give guidance. The ones who know don't tell, the ones who tell don't know ;)

Comment: @bummi what is the direction you are taking about?

Comment: I think the ethical question is still open ended for placebo and double-blind studies, since i provided examples for placebo, double-blind would be like these [The Trouble With Double-Blind Placebo Studies](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/looking-in-the-cultural-mirror/201011/the-trouble-double-blind-placebo-studies) or [Can keeping clinical trial participants blind to their study treatment adversely affect subsequent care?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2945282/)

Comment: @Ooker Yes exactly. You tell everyone of potential side effects but then only a half are actually getting treatment. This is fine with a standard treatment + X (X being the new proposed drug) but if there’s currently *no treatment* (as in your example in the question), it would be highly unethical to  provide X as a life-saving or life-enhancing treatment only to a fraction of the patients. Hence you can’t have a control group, and no double-blind study. And then the placebo effect of side effects may kick in and you have no estimate of the actual side effects.

Comment: @Narusan yes I'm interested in the case of no treatment is available, but without a treatment the patients only continue to suffer the illness, not die. I don't understand the sentence "it would be highly unethical...to a fraction of the patients", can you explain? The control group should be the ones who don't have access to the drug, right? It's just the expectation of the side effects will require the researchers to not fully disclose, or even white-lie, them. I wonder if this is ethical.

Comment: Lying or even just not being fully honest about side effects would be unethical. If it is crucial for a trial that the participants do not know potential side effects, but they insist in knowing them, then it may not be appropriate that they participate.

Comment: @Jan [Is it ethical to deliberately provide incorrect information to participants in **a psychological study**?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21303/12937) The answer seems yes, it is.

Comment: Well, OK, if such approach results in no harm, it might be acceptable, but that's about psychological trials. Physical clinical trials involve the body feelings, which is different than just being misinformed. How would you feel if they say to you, there will be no side effects, and then you would suffer from a significant headache during a trial?

Comment: @Ooker Let’s suppose you have a new medication for pancreatic cancer (a  deadly disease). You need to test it, so you do a double-blind RCT with n=100. 50 of those patients will not be given access to the new, *untested* drug. This is why those studies are supervised all the time, and as soon as there is an indication that the new drug actually heals or decreases mortality, the trial will be stopped and all patients will be given access to the drug. It would be unethical to prevent n=50 from access to treatment.

Comment: [See this post as an example of such ethics considerations](https://www.cancer.net/research-and-advocacy/clinical-trials/placebos-cancer-clinical-trials).

Comment: @Jan well, I think it's the matter of wording. Instead of saying affirmatively "we guarantee that there will be no side effect", they can say "this is a new drug so we don't know much about its side effect, but generally we think there is none". Plus I think they should say that it should be dizzy, so the subjects is expected to feel bad. The point is to let them expect that they will feel bad, but not to let them expect the headache. This would still help them prepared.

Comment: That seems acceptable to me.

Comment: @Narusan I think your comments can be ported as answer. They are informative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 questions here:

1. Is not disclosing potential side effects during a clinical trial ethical?
2. What does the "informed consent" of a clinical trial say about disclosing side effects?

According to [Understanding Informed Consent
 by CenterWatch](https://www.centerwatch.com/clinical-trials/understanding-informed-consent.aspx/):

> If you have given consent to participate in a clinical trial...you are
>   entitled to the following rights:
>
> - To be told about all the risks, side effects, or discomforts that might be reasonably expected...

BUT

> If you want to know details, such as any documented side effects of a
>   particular drug observed in earlier clinical trials, *you must ask*
>   for that information...

...which suggests that they might not tell you the exact side effects if you don't specifically ask them.

BUT,

if you read a [suggestion about informed consent by World Health Organization](https://www.who.int/rpc/research_ethics/InformedConsent-clinicalstudies3.pdf), they say that

> Potential participants *should be told* if there are any known or
>   anticipated side effects...

So, it depends whom you ask and what someone believes about what is good and what not.

---

I think if in previous trials no deaths or other side effects with permanent consequences or other severe side effects have occurred, it may be acceptable to not disclose them - if the participants are informed that they may occur, they agree with this, they believe it's good that they participate in the trial and they are in peace with this.

Or, as said here: [Informed consent in clinical research: Revisiting few concepts and areas (PubMed, 2013)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3601699/):

> **How much or up to what extent the information should be provided on various aspects of research, such as risks and benefits associated
>   with study intervention, is not clear and is rather a subjective
>   approach depending on the investigator.** For example, recounting or
>   repetition of possible adverse effects of a study treatment may make
>   that treatment ill-advised when the treatment is not that risky. On
>   the contrary, if a lately appearing adverse effect is not disclosed to
>   the patient, it raises question on the validity of the consent as the
>   information was not provided adequately. Therefore, researchers are
>   recommended to provide the study-related information adequately,
>   judiciously, and truly maintaining **an ethical balance between
>   expected risks and benefits** of the intervention under investigation.

Comment: Another angle, two really, is apart from investigator's opinion: what gets approved as ethical in a supervisional committee or judged so in a court. That already makes it implicitly clear that US has different standards for that than China.

Comment: so the bottom line here is that there is no consensus and standard?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. It's something what a researcher and a participant need to resolve on a personal level.

Comment: I see. It seems that my question is more about lying, and it seems ethical if the research is a psychological one. What do you think about this? Especially on drugs that affect psychological state?

Comment: If you ask me, lying about significant psychological effects or side effects could be unethical - but again, if the researchers honestly disclose that certain effects and side effects could happen (without specifying them) and if the participants accept that, it might be ethical. But then again, it's what exactly we are talking about. If the researcher is going to hypnotize you without you knowing this in an advance, it can be highly problematic.

Comment: I think I see where this is heading to. Is it ethical to do something seemingly bad to reach something seemingly good? This is answered on the very end of my answer: "...truly maintaining an ethical balance between expected risks and benefits."  Parents often consciously misinform their children to protect them from something bad...This sounds good. But how does this work among adult participants in a clinical trial? A researcher lies about something in a good belief this will be good for a trial or for a participant and then, when finding out, the participant sues the researcher?

Comment: @Jan as per the accepted answer in Psychology SE says, there will be a review board in charge of ethical issues in the research, so there should be no problem. It seems like there is no such committee in medical sciences?

Comment: There _should be_ such a board, but there may be many of them, they may be on the level of the country or a region within a country...and I can't say their names from the head.

Comment: @Ooker In the United States, these boards are called Institutional Review Boards, IRBs, and they are involved in every type of human research, from medical experiments to survey questionnaires of classroom students (the IRB can exempt some human research for review, but it's still up to the IRB). Every developed country I am aware of has something similar, and no reputable journal would publish research that has not undergone a similar review. IRBs will indeed decide if researchers' disclosure is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

At least for psychological study, it seem ethical to deliberately lying to the subjects, as long as the research is review through a committee about ethical issues. [Source](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21303/12937)

In medical study, I think instead of saying affirmatively "we guarantee that there will be no side effect", they can say "this is a new drug so we don't know much about its side effect, but generally we think there is none". Plus I think they should say that it should be dizzy, so the subjects expect them to feel bad. The point is to let them expect that uneasy things will come, but not to let them expect the specific problem. This would still help them prepared.

Comment: This is more comment than answer. If you really want it to be an answer you need to provide supporting references.

Comment: yes, but I think the information is still useful to stand out from the comments

Comment: It's not an answer. It's just a summary of your opinions.

Comment: @CareyGregory  hmm, ok. Is it because it lacks reference? I see in other sites porting informative comments into answers is acceptable. I want to do this to clean up some comments above.

Comment: Converting comments to answers is fine, but the answer still has to answer the question and have supporting references. Your second paragraph is mainly just an explanation of what you **think** and you offer nothing to say your opinions are correct.